# Mirror/invert graph in a repeating bar graph - Altair

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, altair

I am making a repeating bar chart that currently looks like this:

[original graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUn2c.png)

but I need each bar graph to be mirrored so that each graph looks relatively like so:

[mirrored graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Irt.png)

I have experimented with layers, and many parameters but it is difficult to find what code needs to go where in order to do this.

Currently my x axis data is stored in a df as ints, and to invert I simply multiply the df by -1. While I can achieve an inverted graph easily this way in isolation, Altair wont let me layer the two graphs because its a RepeatChart. Here is the code generating the graph below:

```
import altair as alt


base = alt.Chart(df).properties(    
    width=800,
    height=50
)

chart = base.mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('Seconds', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=200, extent=interval), scale=alt.Scale(domain=interval.ref())),
    alt.Y(alt.repeat('row'), aggregate='sum')
).repeat(
    row=list(df.columns)[1:],
)
  
chart
```

Any help is much appreciated! Finally here is a df preview for clarification:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVjkv.png)

Comment: Please do not include images of data. Always put your data in text format, so it can be copy/pasted, or better still post python code that creates your dataframe. This way people will actually be able to use the data to try and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `stack='center'` but note that your y-axis will be harder to read:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 1, 2, 3], y=[0, 1, 2, 1]))
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y=alt.Y('y', stack='center')
)
```

[image]

Ref https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/streamgraph.html